# 'CertUtil' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, certutil

I am trying to verify the validity of a package I downloaded (kubectl) using this command:

`$($(CertUtil -hashfile .\kubectl.exe SHA256)[1] -replace " ", "") -eq $(type .\kubectl.exe.sha256)`

as specified in their [website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-windows) but I get this error:

```
    CertUtil : The term 'CertUtil' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
    Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I added the path to `C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe` to the `Path` env variable but still didn't work.

Comment: Weird: on my PC "CertUtil" can be found on the System32 directory (C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe), is everything ok with your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Can you try appending an ampersand `&` before the CertUtil command like this: `$($(& CertUtil -hashfile .\kubectl.exe SHA256)[1] -replace " ", "") -eq $(type .\kubectl.exe.sha256)`

Comment: yeah the problem was with the path, @Dominique I have the same path as you. But I added the whole path including the filename in the `PATH` variable. It should just be the directory `C:\Windows\System32`